# Can't move node to its own tree using Alfresco's Javascript API

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I've just written a script using the Javascript API so I can use it as a Rule to a Space. Whenever a document enters in a space, it basically checks document's name to get the parent directory it will be stored in (document's name contains parent's folder name), then creates future parent directory (if it doesn't exist), and finally moves the document into it.

I'm having troubles with this last step. Whenever I try to move the document into the recently created folder, I get the following error:

```
Node has been pasted into its own tree.
```

This is my code so far, which I think is pretty much auto-descriptive:

```
var fileName= document.properties.name;
var fields = fileName.split('.');

var parentName= fields[0];
var newNode=space.childByNamePath(parentName);

if (newNode === null) { //create folder and move document into it

  newNode=space.createFolder(parentName);  //works
  document.move(newNode); //I'm getting the error here

}else{ //folder already exists, just move document into it

    document.move(newNode); //here too

}
```

If I comment out the    *document.move(newNode);*   lines everything else works fine. Parent folder is successfully created but obviously the document keeps stored at the root of the current space, which is not what I need. Indeed I need to move it into the actual folder.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Indeed I found out that the *move()* call inside the ***if*** scope it's working if I comment out the other call inside the ***else*** scope. So the error is being thrown at the ***else*** move() call. Also if I remove the ***else*** clause and put just one *move()* call after **if** scope, it also produces the same error.

Comment: Do you use the alfresco debugger to see what's happening ? http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/ws-controller-debug.html

Comment: Isn't this debugger made for client-side Web Scripts? Mine is running on server-side, as a Rule to some concret Space whenever a document enters into this Space.

Comment: Nope, this is a backend javascript debugger. I know for sure it works for backend webscripts, but I can't garantee that it works for script rules. Anyway, I would give it a try because if it works, it will really helps.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it right now!

Comment: I usually use the "break on function enter" in the debbuger menu. It helps to activate the script. The I put my breakpoint, desactivate break on function enter.

Comment: Well bad news when I enable the Javascript Debugger I get a 500 - Interal Error. I've googled it and I'm reading that it won't work on headless servers, and I'm running Alfresco on Debian...

Comment: Please @Akah check answer provided by Lista. It's really helpful and solved the issue perfectly well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run your rule as a background process, it will solve the problem ("Run rule in background" option).

Comment: Nice one ! Could you please edit your answer to explain what's happening ? I'm curious !

Comment: Dude you just saved my day. When you post a problem in StackOverflow you're never expecting to get such a simple, short and precise solution, but this time I can only get on my knees and applaud you.

Comment: Also if you could provide any further explaination about running Rules in background I'd be very grateful

Comment: When you run the rule in background, the rule itself will be executed in a separate transaction (meaning, rule can fail, but the file will still be saved). Now, why the original error happens when the rule is executed in the same transaction, I'm not completely sure.